# How to add item_permission on delete action in easyadmin?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I use **EasyadminBundle** for the Backend of a **Symfony** application.

Two type of users have access to the back-end and I'd like to keep the right to delete to a small number of persons granted with `ROLE_ADMIN`.
I'd like to use `item_permission` parameter as for the other actions (such as `show` or `list`) :

```
Lieu:
    class: App\Entity\Lieu
    list:
        item_permission: ROLE_ENCADRANT
    delete:
        item_permission: ROLE_ADMIN
```

But it's not working and I can still delete user when I'm logged with `ROLE_ENCADRANT`. Is there another solution ?

I currently accomplish it with:

```
Lieu:
    class: App\Entity\Lieu
    list:
        item_permission: ROLE_ENCADRANT
        action: ['-delete']
        help: "the delete button is accessible in <b>Edit</b> view"
    form:
        item_permission: ROLE_ADMIN
```

I'm just looking for a 100% configuration solution, **more elegant than mine**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [adding an action](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/actions-configuration.html) in the docs. The action can be tied to a route, which allows specifying what role may perform the action. The downside is that the list view button is present regardless of role. You can add a flash message to advise the user whether they have permission.

Here's an example from a project. Not quite what you're looking for but may get you started:

easyadmin.yaml:

```
Admin:
    class: App\Entity\Admin
    disabled_actions: ['new', 'edit']
    list:
        actions:
            -
                name: 'admin_enabler'
                type: 'route'
                label: 'Enable/Disable'
```

controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/enabler", name = "admin_enabler")
     */
    public function enabler(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $id = $request->query->get('id');
        $admin = $em->getRepository(Admin::class)->find($id);
        $enabled = $admin->isEnabled();
        if (!$admin->isActivator() && !$admin->hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
            $admin->setEnabled(!$enabled);
            $em->persist($admin);
            $em->flush();
        } else {
            $this->addFlash('danger', $admin->getFullName() . ' cannot be disabled');
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('easyadmin', array(
            'action' => 'list',
            'entity' => $request->query->get('entity'),
        ));    
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is nice but too complicated for my use case. I edit the post with the trick I currently use which is very simple and do the work for now. I didn't tag it as `php` to avoid complexity